# Food Prayed Over By A Idolater

Tags: halacha, tefilla

Is a Jew allowed to eat food that is prayed over by a Christian even if there is no mention of “JC?”

Comment: The Christian 'prayed over' the food. Was this intentional - he deliberately put the food there and then prayed with it in front of him (even maybe requesting that it should nourish the eater) or was he praying and the food just happened to ber there?

Comment: Whose food was it?